# How do I integrate react-native-sensors to my project?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I found [a useful library to detect position of mobile phones](https://github.com/react-native-sensors/react-native-sensors), but I'm not sure how to integrate it to my project as I'm new to both JavaScript and React Native. I tried making it into a class so I can just call it like this `<MotionSensor />` and monitor what it does thru the console. And I'm trying to do this without touching the Android and iOS native code so my code can work for both.

You can take a look at my App.js [here](https://github.com/ignatiusbill/crowd/blob/orientationDetection/App.js).

I use the combination of `create-react-native-app` and Expo.

Any help is greatly appreciated!